# In my native language, we have this idiomatic expression - one has seven Fridays in a week

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

This idiomatic expression is applied to an inconstant person who does not keep his/her word, fulfill promises, often changes his/her mind and isn't trustworthy. Is there an equivalent idiomatic expression in English?

Comment: 'He's as useful as a chocolate teapot' is the saying I know for an unreliable person.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for something that describes two different things.

Somebody who changes their mind a lot:

**fickle**: "marked by lack of steadfastness, constancy, or stability : given to erratic changeableness" (Merriam-Webster online).

Somebody who cannot be trusted to follow through on something:

**unreliable**: "not able to be trusted to do or provide what is needed or promised" (Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary online).

Some possible idiomatic phrases:

**I wouldn't trust them as far as I could throw them.** However, the implication of that may be more about the person being dishonest than simply unreliable.

**At sixes and sevens.** This means being in a state of confusion or disarray. E.g. "He was at sixes and sevens, unable to make up his mind."

**They're not all there.** Somebody is "missing" something that you could normally rely on other people for. E.g., "She's not all there. I wouldn't rely on what she said."

**Full of beans.** Somebody who makes things up or tells "tall tales." This has less to do with erratic behaviour, however, and is more about intentional or unintentional dishonesty.

**Lost the plot.** / **Out to lunch.** Somebody is simply out of touch with normal reality. They behave erratically, and you can't be sure what you're going to get with them.

**Fly-by-night.** Undependable, flighty. (It can apply to things as well as people.)

Comment: +1 for a thorough answer, though I don’t agree it’s really two _different_ things as much as one thing that entails another. As I read the question, the ‘not trustworthy’ bit is not down to generally having an untrustworthy character, but being unreliable specifically because of their fickle, vacillating ways. _Fickle_ is by far the better fit of the two as I read it. I also think _not all there_ is a bit off, since it implies actual mental illness or retardation, which doesn’t seem to be present in the question at all.

Comment: "Full of beans" usually means "enthusiastic".  Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/be-full-of-beans   "Full of it" means someone who makes things up.

Comment: @empty Interesting. I've always heard it the way I used it. But I have found both https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/full%20of%20beans and http://www.idioms4you.com/complete-idioms/full-of-beans.html I've always heard "full of vim and vigour" in reference to being energetic. Perhaps what I'm used to is used mainly in North America.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

1. **To be hot and hold** (= **to blow hot and cold**): *You are hot and cold. I hate it! / 
   You run hot and then you run cold.*
   Do you remember Katy Perry's song *[Hot n Cold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTHNpusq654)*? It's just about the situation you have described.
2. **To be a man/woman of many moods**
3. **To be fickle as the wind**
4. **To change one's mind faster than the weather**
5. **To chop and change** (British, informal)

Answer (score 0):

For 'inconstant' in english, the proper wording is, - inconsistent. America uses inconstant to the context you refer. 
English expressions for 'one has seven fridays in a week'--
'tomorrow never comes', - 'pigs might fly' - 'there is more chance of teachings in history being accurate'. - 'empty promises'

Comment: Are you saying that inconstant and inconsistent are used interchangeably ?

Comment: yes, if one must adhere to misconception of the original english language, as displayed by america and merely the notion of belief that england speaks british. Or britain speaks english. England and english speak english. Britain/british is not a country nor a language.  inconsistent ,is - NOT consistent/constant. Inconstant, in the UK would be used as a phrase basis. 'it's in constant motion'. Therefore, obviously the use or existence of, within the language,  'its inconstant motion' would be bizarre and foolish. UNLESS of course, constant and consistent were a vast difference to begin with?

Comment: CONSTANT- ongoing, continuous, with out break,eternal. infinite. CONSISTENT- regular , of application for purpose,  of same result,  ''consistent results when such application is applied''

Comment: @Adam _Inconstant_ is absolutely used in British English as well; it is by no means an Americanism. It’s just fairly uncommon everywhere. It also means something quite different from _inconsistent_. One describes a personality trait, the other observed behaviour; the two may coincide, or they may not. Also, your first comment is very hard to make sense of; the part about America/Britain/English especially so. _In constant [motion]_ (the preposition _in_ followed by the adjective _constant_) is completely unrelated to the adjective _inconstant_; not sure why you mention that at all.

Comment: [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inconstant%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cinconstant%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinconstant%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinconstant%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows that _inconstant_ is in fact a bit more common in BrE than in AmE, though its use is decreasing everywhere and it’s not frequent in either setting.

Comment: I beg to differ, yet OK, i will take your word for it. P.s There is no such thing as 'British English'.

Answer (score 0):

The state of being inconstant can be expressed by the idiom

> **[blow hot and cold](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blow-hot-and-cold?a=british)** ​ to sometimes like or be interested in something or someone and sometimes not, so people are confused about
>   how you really feel: {[alternate inconsistently between two moods, attitudes, or courses of action](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ucweb-b-bookmark&oq=blow%20hot%20and%20cold&aqs=mobile-gws-lite.0.0l5&q=blow%20hot%20and%20cold%20meaning).}
>
> *He's been blowing hot and cold about the trip to Brazil*

Answer (score 0):

**lost ball in high weeds**  [list of idioms](https://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-alphalists/alpha-list_L/id_L10-lost-lurch.html)

> A person who does not know what they are doing, how to do it or
>   possibly even where they are. John: "What are you doing here!? You
>   can't be here, its dangerous!"
>
> William: "I'm sorry, I got confused as to where i'm supposed to be."
>
> John: "Dude, you're a lost ball in high weeds."